# Understanding setInterval(function() {...}, time)

Tags: javascript

I <strike>understand perfectly</strike> that when you call an anonymous function like this:

```
var assign_Function = function() { *code here...*; } 
// You can now use it like this:
assign_Function();
```

And with objects,

```
A={first_Property:12, second_Property:15}; // Object literal syntax
A.third_Property: function() { *code here...*; }   
A.third_Property(); // Call the method
```

But what happens when function() is put inside a method (or parentheses) which is then assigned to a variable? Like this:

```
var x = setInterval(function() { *some code here*...; }, 1500);
```

is x now x()?

Comment: See [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) for what `setInterval()` does -- it does not return the value from calling the function expression passed.

Comment: That's not an anonymous function since you gave it a name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what happens when function() is put inside a method (or parentheses) which is then assigned to a variable?

In that case, it is a [*FunctionExpression*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.5) that, when evaluated, returns a function object. The function object is then passed to the surrounding code. For example:

```
var fn = function(){/* body */};
bar(fn);
```

is effectively the same as writing:

```
bar(function()/* body */});
```

The only difference is that in the first case, a reference to the function object stored in *fn*, but in the second case no reference is kept. In both cases, *bar* is effectively passed a function object as a parameter.

In the case of:

```
var x = bar(…);
```

then *x* is assigned a value based on the return value of *bar*, it does not reference the parameters passed to *bar*.

Comment: What's the difference between `bar(fn)` and `bar(fn())`?

Comment: @Lexica98: `bar(fn)` passes `fn` to `bar`. `bar(fn())` calls `fn` and passes its return value to `bar`.

Answer (score 3):

No.  `x` is now whatever the return value is from the function you called.  In your case, you called `setInterval()` which returns an ID of an interval, which can be cleared later with `clearInterval()`.

```
var x = setInterval(function() { *some code here*...; }, 1500);

// Later in your code...
clearInterval(x); // Stops the interval from continuing to repeat
```

This isn't any different than returning a value from a different function

```
function returnSomething() {
    return 'test';
}

var y = returnSomething(); // y is now "test"
```

Comment: So function() just returns a value (Or I would make it return a value). There is no need to define the function in any way?

Comment: @Lexica98 In my second example where I have defined a function, you will see that all this function does is return a value.  When you call `x = someFunction()`, the function referenced by the name `someFunction` is executed, and its return value is assigned to `x`.  If the parenthesis are throwing you off, remember that this is normally where you would send in parameters.... `someFunction('param1', 'param2')`

Comment: And you don't have to define the function inside setInterval? Just have it return a value, which will then become a parameter in setInterval? So really all we are saying is that we want a block of statements to execute inside setInterval...? And for that, we use function()?

Comment: Could you use the syntax: var x = setInterval( {var x = "a"; var y = "b"; return x+y;}, 1500); instead of using function()?

Comment: @Lexica98 No!  Absolutely not.  And, how would that make any sense anyway?  `setInterval()` executes a function periodically... every 1500ms in your example.  The first parameter to `setInterval` is a function, and the second is the delay between executions.  You can't just throw an object in there... what would it do?  You need to pass in a function for the first parameter.  You don't have to define that as an anonymous function.  You could always use `setInterval(somefunction, 1500)`

Comment: @Lexica98—per the link provided by Qantas 94 Heavy, the first argument to `setInterval` must be either a function expression, reference or body code.

Comment: Finally, are we saying by typing `setInterval(function(){..}, time)` that we just want a block of statements to run inside `function(){..}`? It's that simple?

Comment: @Lexica98 If I understand what you are asking... yes.  Typing `function () { /* some code */ }` defines an anonymous function... a function without a name.  You're putting that function as the first parameter to `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a variable not a function since return type of `setInterval` is not a function but an Interval Id.

Comment: The statement *"`x` is a variable not a function"* doesn't make a lot of sense. You are comparing apples with oranges.

Comment: You are right. For javascript programmer, it does not make sense.

Comment: I am from a C background. That is why term is like this.

Comment: At the time of writing answer, `Javascript` was not tagged.

Comment: Even in that context the statement is confusing. You are saying that `x` is a variable, not a function because `setInterval` does not return a function but an ID (which is probably a number). So that sounds like a number is a variable, but a function isn't. I'd say that a number is a value and a variable can refer to a value. In JS it happens that functions are values too (and you could argue in C as well, since you have function pointers).